# Directory Structure Recommendation For VPS Host

Tags: linux, web-server, web-hosting

Silly question: I'll be moving about 5-7 small / personal web sites (blogs, forums, web projects, etc) over to a single VPS host and would like recommendations on where to store each site within the linux file system.

My main goals:

- Keep things scalable.  I'd like the structure to allow for future sites.
- Keep things reasonably secure.

Your thoughts?

-M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at FHS:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard
- http://www.pathname.com/fhs/

The old place was /var/www, now I'd argue for using /srv.

I'm also a fan of using /srv/$fqdn/{htdocs,logs,cgi-bin}, etc. But you can do it the other way around also /srv/{htdocs,logs,cgi-bin}/$fqdn. And you can have both. A small script or makefile to update links isn't terribly hard to write.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. 

I like the /srv/$fqdn/{htdocs,logs,cgi-bin} structure as I can keep everything in a central location.

Answer (score 0):

In the linux world, it would often be in /var (some might say /home, etc.).  So the question might be depth vs breadth first:

```
/var/xxx/www
/var/xxx/logs
/var/xxx/db

/var/yyy/www
/var/yyy/logs
/var/yyy/db

vs

/var/www/xxx
/var/www/yyy
/var/logs/xxx
/var/logs/yyy
/var/db/xxx
/var/db/yyy
```

I'd say most lean towards the second.